# Press This for Page

Tags: pages, javascript

I'm new to WP and like to understand is there possible to make browser bookmarklet *Press This* for *Pages* for `wordpress.com`?

If not - probably it's possible for server hosted version, but what should done - do I need to change page template page.php for interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `press_this_save_post` filter can be used to change the post type from `post` to page. Add the following code to your theme's functions.php or a plugin:

```
add_filter( 'press_this_save_post', 'wpse244633_press_this_save_post' );
/**
 * Filter the post data of a Press This post before saving/updating.
 * 
 * @param array $post_data The post data.
 * @return array 
 */
function wpse244633_press_this_save_post( $post_data ) {
    $post_data['post_type'] = 'page';

    return $post_data;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but what about browser because my fault - in the question was missed this part: _for wordpress.com_ ?

Comment: Sorry, but wordpress.com questions are off topic on this site, so in that case the question should be closed.. The above solution would not even be possible on that platform.